# How to retrieve the ordered list of best articles having a minimum number of votes by using HQL?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, grails, hql

I have a `Vote` domain class from my grails application containing properties like `article_id` and `note`

I want to HQL query the `Vote` domain class in order to retrieve the 5 best rated articles having at least 10 votes.

I tried :

```
SELECT v.article_id, avg(v.note), count(*) FROM vote v where count(*) >= 10  group by v.article_id order by avg(v.note) desc limit 5;
```

But unfortunately the insertion of `where count(*) >= 10` throws an error.

How can I do that in a simple way?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not being able to test it, I'm reluctant to try to guess how the final query would look like, but `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10` might be something to look at.

http://www.sqlcommands.net/sql+having/

Answer (score 0):

doesn't the following work ?

```
SELECT v.article_id, avg(v.note), count(*) as count 
FROM vote v 
where count >= 10  
group by v.article_id 
order by avg(v.note) desc limit 5;
```

Later edit: Try this

```
SELECT v.article_id, avg(v.note) 
from vote v 
group by v.article_id 
having count(*) >= 10
order by avg(v.note) desc limit 5;
```

Comment: Not 100% sure but I don't think you can use the count alias in a WHERE in the same query

Comment: Not working at all. It seems that we Cannot use count alias in a WHERE

Comment: ah .. i was afraid of that :(. having the the way to go then.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
SELECT v.article_id, avg(v.note),
FROM vote v 
GROUP BY v.article_id
HAVING count(*) >= 10
OREDER BY avg(v.note) desc limit 5;
```